# Dimensionality of an equation $2x_1 + 6x_3 + 4x_4 = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the equation:

$$2x_1 + 6x_3 + 4x_4 = 0$$

One could represent this with an augmented matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 6 & 4 & | & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & | & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & | & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & | & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Initially, one would immediately assume this matrix is **one dimensional**. Columns 2, 3, and 4 could be said to be redundant, as they all scale by columns 1. So, this would just be a line. However, some of my confusion stems from getting the basis of the subspace in $R^4$. I think this is unlikely, but does the following imply the subspace is in **three dimensions**?

We computed the following bases of the subspace in $R^4$:

$$2x_1 = -6x_3 + -4x_4$$

$$
s\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+
t
\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+
r
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\
0\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Question:**

> Does the bases of the subspace in $R^4$ imply this equation is three dimensional, or is just the bases three dimensional? How would this look geometrically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix is
$$
A = \left\{\begin{matrix} 2&0&6&4\end{matrix}\right\}
$$

since $Ax = 2x_1 + 6x_3 + 4x_4$ where $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T \in \mathbb R^4$.

Now you want to find all $x$ satisfying $Ax = 0$ which is the kernel of $A$. that is of dimension $3$ since obviously our matrix has rank $1$ and $\dim(\ker(A)) + \dim(\text{im}(A)) = \dim(\mathbb R^4)$

To adress the latter question. It makes no sense to say an equation has a dimension. You can say in the linear case atleast that those points fulfilling the equation make up a Vectorspace which has a dimension. I think thats what you want.

If you have nonlinear equation you would not get vectorspaces but you can generalize it to manifolds and then also get a dimension of the resulting manifold the points live on.

I am not sure if one can make this absolutely general. i.e. if you have equations involving absolutely non-continuous functions that  makes defining a dimensino pretty much impossible i guess.

Geometricaly its a hyperplane inside the $\mathbb R^4$

Comment: How is your definition of $Ax$? Is $x$ a column  the vector or a row  vector? If  the matter would be the case you ratver should write $xA$ with  our matrix $A$. Otherwise the matrix from the qustion, $[2\, 0\, 6\, 4]$ would be correct.

Comment: it is a column vector

Comment: Oh what an awful mistake of mine. Thanks @JensSchwaiger. I fixed that.

Comment: Thank you @crush3dice. However, could you explain to me how the matrix is of rank 1, yet geometrically it's a 3-D hyperplane? My assumption was that the matrix is a line, given that it is rank 1.

Comment: I changed that kernel, image formular up there. Have forgottet the dim operator in there.

Comment: since for $v = A^T$ we have $Av = \|v\|_2^2$ we can write every element in $\mathbb R$ as a multiple of $v$. Now lets define $W$ as all elements $w\perp v$ then we get $Aw = \langle v, w\rangle = 0$. Now we can write $\mathbb R^4 = \text{span}(v) \oplus W$ and thus every element $x\in \mathbb R^4$ as $x = (x_1,x_2)$ with $x_1 \in \text{span} (v)$, $x_2 \in W$. Now we get

$$
Ax = Ax_1 + Ax_2 = Ax_1 = \|x_1\|_2^2 = 0 \iff x_1 = 0
$$

as our condition. Now if $w_1,w_2,w_3$ was a basis of $W$ then $v,w_1,w_2,w_3$ is one of $\mathbb R^4$ and all elements $x$ that fulfill the equation have

Comment: the form
$$
x = 0v + \lambda_1w_1 + \lambda_2 w_2 + \lambda_3 w_3
$$
Therefore our solutionspace is $W$ and of dimension $3$